# c# application authorization based on Windows current user

Tags: c#, authorization

I write a small application and I need to add some authorization security tips.

Simple Example: 
I have a WinForm that contain two buttons: btnAdd and btnDelete. I want that:

- if the current user is in the Administrator group, both the two buttons above will be displayed
- else (if not in the Administrator group (like like guess account)) only btnAdd will be displayed.

How can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to construct a [WindowsPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx) object, then just check if the user is in the role you expect, and use the return value to set the button to visible or not.  Something like the below

```
using (WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
{
    WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);

    // using WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator or "BUILTIN\\Administrators" should work
    btnAdd.Visible = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

The updated code works, I've tested this, where I'm a local admin, since you want to test the current user, `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` is actually cleaner.

If you need to confirm whether or not you are an admin on the machine, you can either check the group membership through MMC, but if there is any domain groups involved and you don't have access you won't be able to check this through MMC unless you have access to AD.

A sure way to verify if a user is a member of group is running the below in a command prompt window

**Get members of local Administrators group:**

```
net localgroup administrators
```

**Get members of the domain group:** this is necessary if for example, `mydomain\WorkstationAdmins` is a member of the local Administrators group and *userId* is a member of *mydomain\WorkstationAdmins* (thus an admin of the wokstation)

```
net group "WorkstationAdmins" /domain
```

Comment: I am logged with an account that have type administrator (I check it under control panel) but it give me false also when I am logged with the administrator account.

Comment: `principal.IsInRole(Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)` give me true for the administrator account and note an account that it's type is administrator, it seems to me that my account is not in the administrator group

Comment: @mlivme2 I have updated the answer, if the user is either a member of the local `administrators` group or a member of another group which is a member of this group, it should return true.  I've also added info to help you confirm the user is an admin, in case you need this

Comment: I run the commande `net localgroup administrators` and it tell me that I am in the Administartors group, I tested also `net user CurrentUser` and it give the same.
When I run your code in the Administrator account, the button is visible as expected, but when I run it on my account (which is in the administratorS group) the button is invisible, I don't know why??

Comment: Anyway I accept the answer because its correct, but the problem mentioned in comments still not resolved. Thank you very much for help

Comment: @mlivme2 you will need to test and debug the app, I can confirm the code works as expected, are you positive the user account you're testing with is the right account, have it print out the the user id, etc.